# Basic question concerning indexedDB object store data structure for efficiency in edits versus retrieval of data

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am trying to determine which is the most efficient way to layout data in an indexedDB object store for editing and retrieving. I'm fairly new to these concepts, but the processes of editing and retrieving appear to be opposites in terms of efficiency.

The data I'm dealing with consists of sets of template forms, in which each form, although very similar, can have different numbers of certain pieces of information and different amounts of data for each element. Roughly, though, each form would generally have between 50 and 75 separate data elements, some a boolean value only and others paragraphs of text.

I was planning on saving the data for each form as one entry in an object store.  Then I started considering that all the data for a single form has to be retrieved and re-written to the object store for an edit to a single data element.  That seemed inefficient, and it appeared better to have multiple entries(keys) for each section of data or even each individual data element in a single form.

That may be better for saving edits to individual data elements in a form, but when the data is retrieved to display an existing form, multiple keys of variable number would have to be retrieved instead of one.  So, it appears that what makes saving edits to individual form elements more efficient makes retrieval of all the data for a entire form less efficient.

**So, my question is which is more difficult for the browser?  To extract and replace a larger object of data for a single key, or many individual extractions of smaller objects comprising the same amount of total data?**

Lots of edits will be made but there will also be a lot of moving back and forth between different forms; so, it doesn't appear that one of these processes will take place more or less often than the other making the decision of layout that which makes the most often used most efficient.

I could complicate the code and the data structure in the object store and gain nothing. Or, perhaps, a small set of a fixed number of sections (keys) for each question would split the difference, so to speak.

Thank you for considering my very novice question.

**Added Description**

I'm not trying to complicate things but just understand better.  Please assume there were 1,000 properties total per form.  If a user edits one property only on a form, then either the object storing the 1,000 properties has be retrieved with a `get` and held in a variable, the one property value edited, and then `put` back.  Or, a new object has to be built from all the data in the form and then that object `put` back as an overwrite of the existing object.  So, either way a large object has to be moved and held somewhere outside the database.  There is no way to just alter the one value in the database without pulling out all the data.

Do the steps of locating the key, deserializing the object, and reserializing the object, and whatever else is involved consume a considerable portion of the total time regardless of the size of the actual data object?  Or would there be a significant difference between editing a key holding a single-property object versus editing one property in a key holding an object of 1,000 properties?

If there is a considerable difference, then on the editing side it would save time because I'm almost never going to save all 1,000 properties at once, but only as they are completed, such as in an `onchange` event.  However, on the retrieve-and-display side, perhaps a cursor or an index would be opened on those 1,000 individual keys to retrieve the data and populate the HTML. That, I assume, would take more time that retrieving and holding one large object and using it to populate the HTML.  So there would be some sort of competition between making saving faster versus making retrieving all the form data at once to populate the HTML faster.

I like the one-large-object approach because it simpler to code and follow, but just wanted to understand if there is any visible difference to the user between the two.  Thank you.

After working with this for awhile longer, I think I was stupid in that I should have considered that, since these are both asynchronous processes, saving is the lesser concern for user experience than retrieval.  Populating the screen with new data quickly is more important than saving it quickly.

Comment: Usually the round trip time for individual property or section edits will probably be larger than the round trip time of saving a big object. I think your best best to save the entire form submission event data as a big object of properties. Keep in mind, here, that even if you were to do something like save 1000 properties, it would still be faster to use a big object.

Comment: @Josh Thank you for your response.  If you have a moment could you please let me know if I am misunderstanding?  I added a further description of my question.  I wasn't trying to compare making something like editing 1,000 single-property objects versus a single object of 1,000 properties.  But only one or two properties among the 1,000 at any one time.  Thank you.

Comment: On the order of only a thousand small (e.g. boolean) properties, other-Josh's advice holds. The overhead for a database operation (which involves touching disk) will swamp the cost of serialization. 

If the properties or number of properties were significantly larger (e.g. 1kB text records, or there were 10k of them) then it'd be harder to guess what would be more efficient.

That said: if performance matters, measure it to be sure. If it doesn't matter, write code that will be easier to maintain.